# How to get the number of adresses past every hour for a day

Tags: mysql, sql, time, timestamp

I want to get the number of addresses past in hours from a whole day.

I have tried this, but it didn't work.

```
SELECT FROM_UnixTime((sensordata1.time + 7200), '%Y-%c-%d') "Datum",
       COUNT(DISTINCT sensordata1.address) "Bezoekers"
FROM sensordata1
WHERE 1
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY FROM_UnixTime((sensordata1.time + 7200), '%Y-%c-%d')
```

I want to make a grafiek from it so I can see how many past per hour. I want to see the day and want know from each hour how many things have past. (The address is from a wifi sensor.)

[image: Database I use]

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can put the hour into the from_unixtime:

```
SELECT FROM_UnixTime(sensordata1.time, '%Y-%c-%d %h') "Datum", COUNT(DISTINCT sensordata1.address) "Bezoekers"
FROM sensordata1
WHERE 1
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY FROM_UnixTime((sensordata1.time + 7200), '%Y-%c-%d %h')
```

or you can try:

```
select date(x1.Datum) as "Datum", hour(x1.Datum) as d_hour, count(distinct x1.address) as "Bezoekers"
from 
  (
  select from_unixtime(sensordata1.time) "Datum", sensordata1.address
  from sensordata1
  ) x1
group by date(x1.Datum), hour(x1.Datum)
```